# Securing Registration RESTful API against registering many users

Tags: rest, security

I am developing `RESTful APIs` with `ASP.NET WebAPI` for an `Android application` and there is an option to make a registration through our application. Suppose that our registration endpoint is something like '/api/register/' with some parameters like 'username', 'password' and 'email address'. So this endpoint is likely to be opened not only for Android device, but for everyone.

I mean it is easy to trace all the requests and responses to and from our server, so a bad person may calls this endpoint to start registering many users in our system.

I want to know how I can secure my API?

Comment: Do you need to have the registration API on REST? considered using GCM client to server communication?

Comment: I only know that GCM is a Google service to help developers for implementing notifications. Can it be used for such use cases?

Comment: It also allows client to server messages. You could use that and therefore be sure that the messages come from your APP.

Comment: @jmosawy Have you got the answer of your question? Many people got the same problem as yours and still remain unanswered. Please share if you have solved your problem. I have been waiting for 3 months hoping any 'smart' people post a real answer.

Comment: @SulungNugroho Since I have done a lot of researches, I couldn't find a solution that makes me sure the request is actually coming from our own clients. Throttling, SSL and JWT were the only solutions I could use for the project. I'd be happy if you share any solutions or tricks you found during this period of time you were researching.

Comment: @jmosawy I just apply some delay like 5 minutes after first registration to make second or next registration using browser and ip address session. For Second layer protection, I just use AuthKey. So every client should register the web or mobile app before it can communicate to our web server. That's at least what I can do.

Comment: Your best rescuer is ReCaptcha =)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can take a number of steps to ensure your API can't be called by a random client. These will be effective for 99.9% of the potential threats, but keep in mind that if someone is very committed and is able to decompile your Android app and man-in-the-middle your app's connection, they can still break your security. (I wouldn't worry about such special cases unless you are trying to protect a really high value target.)

For a basic level of protection:

- Only allow SSL connections, and require "**Strict-Transport-Security**"
- Use a shared secret that will be validated on the server (e.g. predefined api key, pre-installed client cert, etc.)
- Throttle API calls on the server
- Ensure that your API does not suffer from other common security pitfalls (use the OWASP Checklist: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

For increased security, you will need to implement some kind of **pre-authentication**, similar to the flow I describe here:

- The client asks for an access token from the server.
- The token is unique to the client and generated using the client IP, request time, and the shared secret. It's also short-lived and set to expire soon.
- The client makes the API call using the unique token while it's still alive.
- The server validates the token, confirms it's coming from the authorized client and processes the API call.

This topic is more complex and unfortunately I haven't come across a simple example that I can point you to.

Comment: Can you explain further how to generate a pre-authenticated token? How to secure the pre authenticated token API? The attacker can also call the pre authenticated token api